# Avoid duplicating OSGi imports in maven dependancies?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, osgi

Currently when I am writting a bundle in that depends on a package, I have to "import" or "depend" on a whole other bundle in Maven that contains that package.

This seems like it is counter-productive to what OSGi gives me.

For example let's say I have two bundles: BundleAPI and BundleImpl.

BundleAPI provides the API interfaces:

```
// BundleAPI's manifest
export-package: com.service.api
```

BundleImpl provides the implementation:

```
//BundleImpl's manifest
import-package com.service.api
```

However, when I am coding **BundleImpl** in Eclipse, I am forced to "depend" in maven POM on **BundleAPI** itself - so that eclipse does not complain.

```
//BundleImpl's POM
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.service</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.service.api</artifactId>
    [...]
</dependency>
```

So - on one hand, I am depending only on the *package* **com.service.api**, while on the other - I need to have the whole bundle - **BundleAPI**.

Is there a way to make maven or eclipse smart enough to just find the packages somewhere, instead of whole bundles?

I am very much confused as to how this works - any type of clarity here would be great. Maybe I am missing something fundamentally simple?

Comment: Found a good blog post about this: http://mattiasholmqvist.se/2010/02/building-with-tycho-part-1-osgi-bundles/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key is to distinguish between build-time dependencies and runtime dependencies.

At build time you have to depend on a whole artifact, i.e. a JAR file or bundle. That's pretty much unavoidable because of the way Java compilers work. However at runtime you depend only on the packages you use in your bundle, and this is how OSGi manages runtime substitution. This is the Import-Package statement in your final bundle.

Of course as a developer you don't want to list two parallel sets of dependencies, that would be crazy. Fortunately maven-bundle-plugin is based on a tool called bnd that calculates the Import-Package statement for you based on analysing your code and discovering the actual packages used. Other tools such as bndtools (an Eclipse-based IDE for OSGi development) also use bnd in this way. Incidentally bnd is much more reliable and accurate than any human at doing this job!

So, you define only the module-level dependencies that you need at build time, and the tool generates the runtime package-level dependencies.

I would recommend against using Tycho because it forces you to use Eclipse PDE, which in turn forces you to manually manage imported packages (for the sake of full disclosure, I am the author of bndtools which competes against PDE).

Comment: "The key is to distinguish between build-time dependencies and runtime dependencies." - Thanks that was precisely my confusion!

Comment: I have to agree with the pitfall of Tycho, but you have to balance that against the more seamless integration into your IDE, which can make development much simpler.  But for that to work, you will need a p2 repo in place.  p2 has its own set of capabilities as well with regard to deployment of your plugins and product, which is great if you are going to make use of those capabilities.  If not, then Tycho may not be for you.

Comment: Nice job on the bnd tools by the way, I used the bundle plugin for a couple of years and it works quite well.

Comment: @Robin: Tycho seamlessly integrates with Eclipse PDE, but it's a mistake to consider that the only IDE available for OSGi. Maven bundle plugin seamlessly integrates with m2eclipse, especially if you use it with bndtools.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot develop bundles like regular Java projects with Maven and eclipse.  You basically have 2 options.

- [Apache Felix Bundle Plugin](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html): Basically you develop the project as a regular Java project and use Maven as you normally would.  This plugin will be used to add all the OSGi specifics to the jar manifest at deployment time to OSGi enable it.  The disadvantage of this aproach is that you are using a Java project in your workspace instead of a bundle, which makes running your project in the OSGi container a little extra work since Eclipse doesn't recognize it as a plugin project.  Thus you have to add the jar from the Maven build as part of the target platform manually.
- [Tycho](http://tycho.sonatype.org/): This is another Maven plugin that attempts to actually bring theses two environments together and does a pretty good job of it.  In this scenario, you actually create an Eclipse bundle/plugin project, which obviously makes for seamless integration in Eclipse.  The pom then marks the project as being an eclipse-plugin type, which effectively makes Maven resolve the project dependencies (defined in the manifest) via the target platform instead of Maven itself.

I would take the Tycho approach as it gives a much more integrated approach with Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks, I was using maven-bundle-plugin, but that resulted in me duplicating the dependancies like I described. This Tycho option is interesting I'll take a look. How does it know where to take the "imported-package" though? Does it look at local maven repo - and recognise package-exports?

Comment: Wow, Tycho documentation is really Bad - it's missing all kinds of special characters for me (in Chrome and Firefox): http://tycho.sonatype.org/how-to-create-a-new-osgi-bundle.html

Comment: @drozzy: unfortunately, formatting is not the worst thing about their documentation :) Tycho works really well, though, unless you are trying to implement advanced use-cases.

Comment: The duplication that you mention is not a problem with maven-bundle-plugin. At the Maven level you need to refer to the whole jar file as a dependency, as usual, but maven-bundle-plugin will do the right thing and generate the correct package imports. You can check that by looking at target/classes/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF after building.

Comment: @Bertrand Delacretaz - I understand, but I still have to refer to the WHOLE "jar" as a dependency. I am wandering if that were poses a problem in the future?

Comment: @drozzy - No, it does not pose a problem.  It is only a build dependency anyway since the runtime dependency will resolve like any other OSGi bundle.  Your pom has no impact at this point.

Comment: @drozzy - As for tycho, it will resolve the dependencies from configured p2 repos from maven, and your defined target platform from Eclipse.  You may be able to use the target platform for the maven build as well, but I am not sure since my experience with Tycho is limited at this point.

Comment: So in order for Tycho to find the "imported" package - the bundle that provides it must published/pushed to this (p2) repo thing? Is this similar to how local maven .m2 (or obr) repository works?

Comment: Please bear in mind that Tycho is a build tool for projects that have been developed in Eclipse PDE. If the project has not been developed with PDE then Tycho is not the right solution.

Comment: Yes, my answer is based on the fact that he is using Eclipse as the dev environment.  I have a bias to the seamless integration for development purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Having the whole jar as a dependency shouldn't be a problem, that's how you have to do it with Maven anyway.